# Show GMT Offset in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time, gmt

I have a timezone database from https://timezonedb.com/download

Each Time Zone row queried has one time_start field and another field called gmt_offset

For example one row would be

```
        [zone_id] => 191
        [zone_name] => Asia/Kolkata
        [country_name] => India
        [time_start] => -891582800
        [gmt_offset] => 23400
        [dst] => 0
```

What I need to display from this is the Country and the GMT Offset like this  via PHP

```
India: GMT +5:30
```

I've tried

```
            $plusoffset = $row->time_start+$row->gmt_offset;
            $minusoffset = $row->time_start-$row->gmt_offset;
            echo "Time Start: ". date('h:i:s',$row->time_start).'<br>';
            echo "Offset: ". date('h:i:s',$row->gmt_offset).'<br>';
            echo "Start+Offset: ". date('h:i:s',$plusoffset).'<br>';
            echo "Start-Offset: ". date('h:i:s',$minusoffset).'<br>';
```

But none of these show the correct offset.

I'm sure I'm missing something glaringly obvious but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just translate the seconds you got there (23400) to hours and minutes...

```
$gmt_offset = 23400;

$hours = (int)($gmt_offset / 3600);
$minutes = $gmt_offset % 3600 / 60;
echo 'Offset: ' . $hours . ':' . $minutes;
```

Comment: It still shows one hour extra. Eg. instead of showing 5:30 it shows 6:30.

Comment: 23400 is for sure 6.5 hours (you can divide by 3600 to see yourself)
You should ask probably why it is 23400.